# running AWK script gives me syntax errors

Tags: linux, awk

I am trying to find romanized korean names from a text file containing names and identify the count of types of matches, then print the count. To do this, I made an AWK script but running this script gives me syntax errors for the regex variable and the second block around `'{' '}'`. The regex variable holds my regex pattern.

This is my code:

```
BEGIN { 
    correctMatch = 0; 
    falsePositive = 0; 
    falseNegative = 0; 
    correctNonMatch = 0;  
    regex = (g|kk|n|d|tt|r|m|b|pp|s|ss|j|jj|ch|tch|k|t|p|h)?(a|ae|ya|yae|eo|e|yeo|ye|o|wa|wae|oe|yo|u|wo|we|wi|yu|eu|ui|i|oo|ah)(k|n|t|l|m|p|ng)? (g|kk|n|d|tt|r|m|b|pp|s|ss|j|jj|ch|tch|k|t|p|h)?(a|ae|ya|yae|eo|e|yeo|ye|o|wa|wae|oe|yo|u|wo|we|wi|yu|eu|ui|i|oo|ah)(k|n|t|l|m|p|ng)?-?(g|kk|n|d|tt|r|m|b|pp|s|ss|j|jj|ch|tch|k|t|p|h)?(a|ae|ya|yae|eo|e|yeo|ye|o|wa|wae|oe|yo|u|wo|we|wi|yu|eu|ui|i|oo|ah)(k|n|t|l|m|p|ng)?;
}

    {
        $NF=="Korean" && tolower($0)~regex {correctMatch = correctMatch + 1}
        $NF!="Korean" && tolower($0)~regex {falsePositive = falsePositive + 1}
        $NF=="Korean" && tolower($0)!~regex {falseNegative = falseNegative + 1}
        $NF!="Korean" && tolower($0)!~regex {correctNonMatch = correctNonMatch + 1}
    }

END {
    print "Correct Match:" correctMatch;
    print "False Positive:" falsePositive;
    print "False Negative:" falseNegative;
    print "Non Correct-Match:" correctNonMatch;
}
```

Comment: Presumably you intended `regex` in the BEGIN block to be defined as a string expression (i.e. enclosed in quotes)? See for example [Using Dynamic Regexps](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#index-regular-expressions-9)

Comment: yes that helped for the regex variable, thank you so much. But it still shows syntax error for the parenthesis around the second block. any thoughts on that?

Comment: The outer braces are erroneous - an awk program should consist of `rule {action}` pairs - not `{rule{action}}`

Comment: solved it by adding if and else if conditions to each of the rules, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, you can't just have conditions before actions inside an awk action part (i.e. between `{...}`) any more than you could have them in a C program. To fix that and address other issues of inefficiency and unnecessary code duplication change it to:

```
BEGIN {  
    regex = "(g|kk|n|d|tt|r|m|b|pp|s|ss|j|jj|ch|tch|k|t|p|h)?(a|ae|ya|yae|eo|e|yeo|ye|o|wa|wae|oe|yo|u|wo|we|wi|yu|eu|ui|i|oo|ah)(k|n|t|l|m|p|ng)? (g|kk|n|d|tt|r|m|b|pp|s|ss|j|jj|ch|tch|k|t|p|h)?(a|ae|ya|yae|eo|e|yeo|ye|o|wa|wae|oe|yo|u|wo|we|wi|yu|eu|ui|i|oo|ah)(k|n|t|l|m|p|ng)?-?(g|kk|n|d|tt|r|m|b|pp|s|ss|j|jj|ch|tch|k|t|p|h)?(a|ae|ya|yae|eo|e|yeo|ye|o|wa|wae|oe|yo|u|wo|we|wi|yu|eu|ui|i|oo|ah)(k|n|t|l|m|p|ng)?"
}
{
    hitNf = ( $NF == "Korean" )
    hitRe = ( tolower($0) ~ regex )
    correctMatch   += (  hitNf &&  hitRe )
    falsePositive  += ( !hitNf &&  hitRe )
    falseNegative  += (  hitNf && !hitRe )
    correcNonMatch += ( !hitNf && !hitRe )
}
END {
    print "Correct Match:" correctMatch+0
    print "False Positive:" falsePositive+0
    print "False Negative:" falseNegative+0
    print "Non Correct-Match:" correctNonMatch+0
}
```

With the above structure you could obviously just test the regexp directly instead of storing it in a variable first. By the way, in your code you have `regex = foo` - that isn't storing the regexp in a variable named `regex`. I fixed that for you above to be `regex = "foo"` (a dynamic regexp) but newer versions of GNU awk also support storing a static regexp in a variable using `regex = @/foo/`. See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Computed-Regexps and https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Regexp-Constants.

Comment: thanks Ed, got a clear understanding.